# Sliced OpenSCAD model has face inside the object

Tags: 3d, openscad

I have a cube from I cut out few places. Exported STL consist from a base with closed face and then it continues as if it was new object.

Am I somehow able to convince OpenSCAD to keep it as one object? Or is it even up to OpenSCAD?

- https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2242402 (scad and stl file)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwDkZ.jpg (what I see in slicer)

Comment: seems like you could try a more liberal application of unions and differences

Comment: if you're on windows, you might also be able to just repair the object in 3D Builder.